# Spring/Resin configuration problem

Tags: java, spring, resin, web-inf

I am wiring up a servlet thru spring running inside resin.. When the web app starts up i get

> [11-02-22 12:12:36.259] {main} org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [/WEB-INF/*-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>                                   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java

I indeed have my spring configuration files in

```
WEB-INF/
```

as

```
WEB-INF/persist-context.xml
```

and the `web.xml` file does have

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dsservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/*-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

all of this works fine in jetty, but in resin (again) i get the error:

```
ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I have added a line in resin.conf like

```
<web-app id="/myapp" root-directory="$/path/to/myapps/explodedwardir"/>
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Initial Answer

Note the error text: **/WEB-INF/*-context.xml**
Now, note your text: ***WEB-INF/dsservlet-servlet.xml*** 
*-context.xml will never match *-servlet.xml

### More stuff

I include the following in the Spring Dispatch Servlet (in the web.xml file) when I want the Dsipatch Servlet to reference the contextConfigLocation config-param in my web.xml.

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: my apologies and good catch. dsservlet-servlet.xml gets pull automagically based on the name of the servlet. So i was wrong to even mention that file. The *context.xml is where the eclipselink persistence.xml stuff is stored as in persist-context.xml. i will fix the original post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/WEB-INF/*-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

(adding `classpath:` prefix).

Comment: doing such i get

[11-02-22 18:23:46.428] {main} org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [classpath:/WEB-INF/*-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist